# @PathVariable is not working in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have `PersonController` as below :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("person")
public class PersonController {

@RequestMapping(value= "/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json"})
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") Integer personId) { 
    // code to get person
}
```

Tomcat starts up fine, I see this in the console :

```
Mapped "{[/person/{personId}],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[] ,consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object> com.test.web.controller.PersonController.getPerson(java.lang.Integer)
```

But if I hit the url `http://localhost:8080/sample/person/1` I get

```
HTTP Status 404 - /sample/person/1
```

In the web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <!--init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param-->
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/sample/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How about the configuration?

Comment: Could you please post your Spring configuration?

Comment: does your accept header include application/json?

Comment: try to put also the log file...when the server starts if u have log4j enabled it should say all the mapped controllers...if you don't see the PersonController listed in that file...well I guess you have to check your spring configrution

Comment: Can you reach any other addresses there? Have you tried a leading slash on the mapping? Do you have a content type in your request?

Comment: Did you try removing the `produces` attribute?

Comment: And your dispatcher servlet is mapped to /sample?

Comment: Yeah why are you expecting /sample to work. Show your web-inf too

Comment: What happens if you change the mapping to `/sample/` instead of '/sample/*'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy/pasted your PersonController class and it worked fine here.

So I did check your web.xml and your app servlet is mapping the pattern **"/sample/*"**.

If I am corret, I suspect your project is called "sample" in Eclipse. In that case, you have to access your site as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/sample/sample/person/1
```

The mapping in your web.xml will always start from your root context, and that is why you are getting 404 error.

If you want to access your controller from the root domain (in this case it is your actual Eclipse project name by default, but it can be configured too) you can use your servlet mapping as follows:

```
<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I recommend that you use /rest/* or other mark since it will scale better for other types of content.

Let me know if it worked.